# Recursively select all child ids and join in one string using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a category model look like this:

```
public class Category
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
  public string ChildIDs { get; set; }
}
```

I want to Recursively select all child ids and join in ChildIDs like this: **12,13,17,31**

This is my Linq query, but it returns **1 level** childern:

```
from cg in db.Categories
where cg.Id == id
join urc in
    (from x in db.UrlRecords where x.EntityName == "Category" select x) on cg.Id equals urc.EntityId into urccg
from f in urccg.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    cg,
    f,
    ParentCategoryId = cg.ParentCategoryId,
    ChildIds = string.Join(",", (from x in db.Categories where x.ParentCategoryId == cg.Id select x.Id))
}
```

Comment: so what is problem coming?

Comment: I need all of child of children, but this returns first level children

Comment: I don't think you could do it recursively in a single query, you would have to write a recursive method. Have you considered modelling your data differently. If you had a `ParentId`foreign key property and a `Children` navigation property your life would be much easier.